# Using case object to satisfy abstract type member

Tags: scala, case-class, abstract-type

I have an architecture where I have a concept of a `Component` that is instantiated dynamically at run-time from a static configuration and/or run-time data. The static part of the data is provided as a `Definition` type, which each component must override within its companion object, along with a `configurationReads` to deserialize it from JSON.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait ComponentDefinition // Intentionally empty

trait ComponentCompanion {
  type Definition <: ComponentDefinition
  def configurationReads: Reads[Definition]
}
```

For components with static options, I supply a `case class` for the `Definition` type:

```
class ParticularComponent { /* blah */ }

object ParticularComponent extends ComponentCompanion {
  case class Definition(option1: String, option2: Boolean) extends ComponentDefinition
  val configurationReads = Json.reads[Definition]
}
```

This works great. In the past, I've used an empty `case class` for components that have no static options, but I know that a `case object` would be more idiomatic. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. If I try:

```
class OptionlessComponent { /* blah */ }

object OptionlessComponent extends ComponentCompanion {
  case object Definition extends ComponentDefinition
  val configurationReads = Reads.pure(Definition)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:19: error: overriding method configurationReads in trait ComponentCompanion of type => play.api.libs.json.Reads[OptionlessComponent.Definition];
 value configurationReads has incompatible type
             val configurationReads = Reads.pure(Definition)
```

Is there a way to make this work with `case object` in analogy to the `case class` version?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `case object` is creating a new `Definition` name in the value namespace, but not overloading the abstract `type Definition` in the type namespace. So this compiles:

```
class OptionlessComponent { /* blah */ }

object OptionlessComponent extends ComponentCompanion {
  case object Definition extends ComponentDefinition
  type Definition = Definition.type
  val configurationReads = Reads.pure(Definition)
}
```

Obviously, this isn't exactly an unqualified win over the empty params `case class` version:

```
class OptionlessComponent { /* blah */ }

object OptionlessComponent extends ComponentCompanion {
  case class Definition() extends ComponentDefinition
  val configurationReads = Reads.pure(Definition())
}
```

If I'm missing something that would allow me to combine the elegance of both of these options, I'm open to suggestions.